# font awesome instagram icon invisible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I've added the instagram font awesome icon to the navbar but its invisible - all other social icons are showing.

The instagram logo is menu-item-303.

I think all the info is below, however let me know if not - this is my first post here.

```css
header .navbar-nav li a i {
    font-size: 18px;
}

header .nav.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-23 > a, header .nav.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-24 > a, header .nav.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-25 > a {
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 5px;
}

header .nav.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-26 > a  {
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 12px;
}

header .nav.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-303 > a  {
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav mobile-hidden expandable"><li class="main alt-bg-color mobile-menu-toggle">
                                <button type="button" class="fa fa-cancel"></button>
                            </li><li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-left menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-249"><a href="http://hhhhappy.com/new-music/">MUSIC</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-268" class="menu-left menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-268"><a href="http://hhhhappy.com/arts/">ARTS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-269" class="menu-left menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-269"><a href="http://hhhhappy.com/news/">NEWS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-270" class="menu-left menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-270"><a href="http://gigs.hhhhappy.com/">GIG GUIDE</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-271" class="menu-left menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-271"><a href="http://store.hhhhappy.com/">MAG</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-26"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HappyMusicFestival"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-303" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-303"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/happymagtv/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/happy"><i class="fa fa-soundclowd"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/happymagtv"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/happymagtv"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="no-link menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="#">A gig guide from the creators of Happy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry unsure how to edit - site is: gigs.hhhhappy.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your font awesome css file has the class name written as fa-instagramm, with 2 M's instead of one. There are a few ways to solve this:
**1.** Go to 
wp-content/themes/musicpeople/includes/vendors/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css and find

```
.fa-instagramm:before
```

and change it to

```
.fa-instagram:before
```

**2.** Just add this to your css file

```
.fa-instagram:before { content: '\e987'; }
```

Solution 2 might be better in case you update the theme and it still has the typo inside the font awesome css file. Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Hi LL, welcome to SO. Thanks for trying to help, but I'd like to suggest that it  would be a bad idea to modify the standard CSS of fontAwesome only to fix a typo (as identified by Michael Coker). The user would risk compatibility if he ever upgraded to a new version of FA...

Comment: @Mbaas Hmm, I think you are mistaken, take a look here https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css#L1218-L1220. It seems to me the typo is in the users (or rather the WP themes) FA css file. This is why I suggested to rather edit the css file he is using than the FA one, since he could upgrade his theme and the typo would come back if the theme authors don't catch it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh well, you are right! It's long time that I used WP, so I did not realize that this typo came through a theme which has already modified `fontawesome.css`. That feels horrible - but maybe there were reasons for it... In that case your solution is certainly applicable - but otoh, if a themer does such things - he hopefully had a good reason for it, and editing it would then create problems, too. So I think Michael Coker's solution "feels" better as it is less invasive and only affects user-code...

Comment: I agree, the changed css makes no sense at all, especially since it's such a weird one. And then the icons used by the theme have the correct class name, not the edited one! Michael Coker's solution is less invasive and definitely more 'correct', I just assumed that this will be easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your [font awesome CSS file](http://gigs.hhhhappy.com/wp-content/themes/musicpeople/includes/vendors/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css), the classname is `fa-instagramm`.

Update your `i` tag to be `<i class="fa fa-instagramm"></i>` and it should work.